# How to create a Nullable<T> from a Type variable?

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm working with expressions and I need a method which receives an object of *some type* (currently unknown). Something like this:

```
public static void Foobar(object Meh) { }
```

What I need to is make this method return a `Nullable<T>` version of `Meh`, but the type `T` is from `Meh.GetType()`. So the return would be `Nullable<MehType>`, where `MehType` is the type of `Meh`.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

**Update:** the reason why I needed this is because of this exception:

*The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.*

```
return Expression.Equal(leftExpr, rightExpr);
```

where `leftExpr` is a `System.Nullable1[[System.Int32` and `rightExpr` is a `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the type at compile time, the only way of expressing it is as `object` - and as soon as you box a nullable value type, you end up with either a null reference, or a boxed *non-nullable* value type.

So these snippets are *exactly equivalent* in terms of the results:

```
int? nullable = 3;
object result = nullable;

int nonNullable = 3;
object result = nonNullable;
```

In other words, I don't think you can really express what you're trying to do.

Comment: After reading your, recursive's and FishBasketGordo's obversations, I understand it's impossible to express this. So I got find do it in the other way: make a nullable back to the original type.. inside an expression!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use `Meh.GetType()` instead of a generic? What about this?

```
public static Nullable<T> Foobar<T>(T Meh) where T : struct { }
```

I'm making the assumption that "some type" does not mean "any type", because the solution above would only work with value types.

Comment: Needs a `where T : struct` constraint.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work. The type of `Meh` is `object` (but it can be a `string`, `Int32` or something else). The error says _The type 'object' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as paramater 'T' in the generic type or method ..._.

Comment: So, you need a method that returns a nullable type only if the runtime type of the argument is a value type?

Comment: What do you mean with _value type_?

Comment: C# has reference types and value types. In general, reference types live in heap memory and can be null of their own rite, and value types live in stack memory and must have a value, i.e. cannot be null on their own. (There are more subtleties than that, but that's a larger discussion.) That's why we have the Nullable<T> struct, to make value types behave a little bit like reference types.

Comment: @ricardo: `Nullable<string>` cannot exist.  Try it out and see!  `Nullable<T>` only is legal for non-nullable types of `T`.