# Can I force an expression to be used with a non-nullable parameter?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nullable, non-nullable

I'm not sure how to explain this, so I'm gonna show you some code first and explain what it does.

Extension `Filter`: receives a parameter expression and a special type of filter I've built for my application (`IFilter`).

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Filter<TSource, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expression, IFilter f)
{
    if (!f.IsEmpty())
    {
        string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        source = source.Where(f.GetWhereLambda<TSource>(propertyName));
    }

    return source;
}
```

Currently, it's possible to do this (simplified!):

```
var Foo = db.Foos
.Select(e => new
{
    ID = e.ID, // Primary key.
    Bar = e.BarID // Some nullable FK.
})
.Filter(e => e.Bar, this.someSpecialFilter);
```

So, there's a problem over there. `BarID` can be null, so the EF is generating a POCO class using `int?`, which is fine for me, but not for my expression processing. This problem first originated this question: [How to create a Nullable<T> from a Type variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070791/how-to-create-a-nullablet-from-a-type-variable).

The problem description:

The exception *The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.* is throwed from this code:

```
return Expression.Equal(leftExpr, rightExpr);
```

where leftExpr is a `System.Nullable1[[System.Int32` (the paramater, as `int?`) and rightExpr is a `System.Int32` (the value, as  Int32`).

The question:

Can I do something to avoid the **?** from `int?`? I mean, is it possible to avoid receiving a nullable type or should I check for this in my code?

Thanks a lot,

Ricardo

Comment: I just realized that `string` might be a problem.

Comment: why is the foreign key nullable? In most situations keys are not nullable. If you have full control over the database, then either make the foreign key non-nullable or make another uniquely generated key for the table that is not nullable (seems like these should be the most straightforward options).

Comment: Have you tried  Bar = e.BarID ?? Int32.MinValue // or default(int)

Comment: @Lirik: there are situations where th FK is nullable. I actually have full control over the db, but there's the legacy part which is way complicated to change. Sometimes you just don't have something in the relationship, and I think that's normal.

Comment: @sllev: use `Int32.MinValue` is not an option. This would kill the FK in the database when I try to update/add the entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution I've found is use the navigation property and just throw an exception when something is Nullable.

```
    if ((expression.ReturnType.IsGenericType) && (expression.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        throw new Exception("The property expression cannot be Nullable.");
    }
```

And the use is something like this:

```
var Foo = db.Foos
.Select(e => new
{
    ID = e.ID, // Primary key.
    Bar = e.Bar.ID // Use the PK from Bar's navigation property.
})
.Filter(e => e.Bar, this.someSpecialFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

> Can I do something to avoid the '?' from 'int?' ?

and then you explain this:

> there are situations where th FK is nullable

So i understand you can't avoid the nullable type

this may be a conception issue, or i miss something there